# PHP Catchable fatal error in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.3

I have a site I developed with Laravel 5, all of a sudden I have been having this error and I did not make any changes.

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to RecursiveIteratorIterator::__construct() must be an instance of Traversable, instance of Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\ExcludeDirectoryFilterIterator given, called in /home/reor/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 571 and defined in /home/reor/vendor/symfony/finder/Finder.php on line 675

The site is hosted on a shared hosting account. Can anyone help with what could have caused this error.
Thanks

Comment: Seriously, with so little info we are just as clueless as you are. Try to debug it. Look at that finder file and see what you can figure out.

Comment: if you haven't changed anything clearing any server caches would be my first step

Comment: Remove your `compiled.php` file. `php artisan clear-compiled`. Or run `php artisan optimize` on your server.